# Access GeoNetwork thumbnail images on any local server? Relative path issue?

Tags: geonetwork

I've installed GeoNetwork via Docker on an Ubuntu server for use internally with a volume to the host `/host/geonetwork-docker:/var/lib/geonetwork_data`

I've got 1560 records to import via XML and have thumbnail images for all of them, both on the Ubuntu server GeoNetwork and on a separate windows server used internally as a data repository.

I've tried putting the images in `/host/geonetwork-docker/data/Thumbnails/Geo_125k/XXXXX.jpg` and using the below path in the XML

```xml
         <gmd:graphicOverview>
            <gmd:MD_BrowseGraphic>
               <gmd:fileName>
                  <gco:CharacterString>/data/Thumbnails/Geo_125k/XXXXX.jpg</gco:CharacterString>
               </gmd:fileName>
               <gmd:fileDescription>
                  <gco:CharacterString>Thumbnail</gco:CharacterString>
               </gmd:fileDescription>
               <gmd:fileType>
                  <gco:CharacterString>JPEG</gco:CharacterString>
               </gmd:fileType>
            </gmd:MD_BrowseGraphic>
         </gmd:graphicOverview>
```

This didn't work so also tried the full path from the host and from the container and still no luck.

I've also tried using the path to the files local windows server `http://gdcs1/Metadata/Thumbnails/Geo_125k/XXXXX.jpg` which also doesn't work.

Anyone have any suggestions/ideas? Is this a docker issue?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Had server address incorrect.

Path should be `http://gdcs1.gdc.com/Metadata/Thumbnails/Geo_125k/XXXXX.jpg`